# How do I calculate the differential cross section with respect to the transversal momentum?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, scattering-cross-section

First of all, sorry for my English, my first language is German.

My problem is: I calculated the matrix element of the quark-gluon-Compton process (q+g -> gamma + q). With the kinematics of scattering in the center-of-mass frame, i could calculate dsigma/dt. This differential cross section only depends on the Mandelstam variables.
Later on I should include the parton distribution functions to calculate the differential cross section (with a Monte Carlo Simulation). My end result should be the differential cross section with respect to the transverse momentum of the direct photon.

So how do i transform my dsigma/dt to dsigma/dp without including the PDFs? I want to know how I accomplish this task in general before messing around with the PDFs.

Thank you all!

Comment: The result depends on the Mandelstam variables, as you wrote, but they are $s,t,u$ and at least two of them, $s,t$, are independent, right? So why are you only talking about $dt$ and not $ds$? I think that at the end, you are calculating the process at the parton level so PDF doesn't enter at all, as you correctly or optimistically anticipated, and $s,t$ as well as $p,E$ (?) describe properties of the elementary particles (and partons) and there is a simple transformation from some variables to others, right?

Comment: I only talk about $dt$ because I derived the differential cross section this way. The general formula for a 2->2 body scattering problem is: $\frac{d\sigma}{dt} =\frac{1}{64 \pi s p_i^{2,*}} |M|^2$. But how can I transform $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$ to $\frac{d\sigma}{dp_t}$. But as I wrote these lines I have an idea. I will try it out. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Okay, I tried several methods, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

The process is discussed at the parton level – both in the initial form and the desired form – so the conversion cannot depend on PDFs.

Now, the [Mandelstam variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) $t$ is equal to
$$ t = (p^\mu_1 - p^\mu_3)^2 = m_1^2+m_3^2 -2 E_1 E_3 +2 \vec p_1\cdot \vec p_3 $$
in the "mostly minus" metric convention. The masses of particles are fixed and the total energy is given by the initial state. We need to find a relationship between $t$ and the transverse momentum $p_t$ and between their differentials. The inner product of the 3-vectors is the key to the transverse/longitudinal split:
$$\vec p_1\cdot \vec p_3 = p_1^L p_3^L + \vec p_1^T\cdot \vec p_3^T $$
The initial state has $\vec p^T_{1,2}=0$ so the second term may be dropped. On the other hand, the only scattering-angle-dependent quantity is 
$$p_3^L = \sqrt{p_{3,\rm max}^2 - (p_3^T)^2} $$
So
$$ t = m_1^2+m_3^2-2E_1E_3+2 p_1^L \sqrt{p_{3,\rm max}^2 - (p_3^T)^2} $$
This is a relationship between $t$ and $p^T$ and you may differentiate it to find the relationship between $dt$ and $dp^T$. There is a lot of uninsightful calculation need to be done and I think it should be done by you at the end.

Comment: I struggle with the understanding of the second and third equation. Where do they come from? Btw. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ShawnHellmann write $\vec p_i=\vec p_i^L+\vec p_i^T$ with $\vec p_i^L\cdot \vec p_j^T=0$.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. I am referring to your last equation: $\frac{d\sigma}{d p_3^T} = \frac{d\sigma}{dt} \frac{dt}{dp_T^3}$. Now: $\frac{dt}{dp_T^3} = 2p_1^L \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{p_3^2-p_3^{T,2}}}\cdot (-2 p_3^T)$. But this is zero, isn't it? And why can I replace $p_3^L$ in your second equation. It's not a vector. How I do I make sure that $\vec p_1^L \vec p_3^L = p_1^L p_3^L $ holds?

Comment: The last equality follows tautologically because if you define the longitudinal parts of the 3-vectors as vectors at all, they are 1-dimensional vectors, so the inner product of the vectors is the same as the product of the "only components". No, the derivative of $t$ with respect to $p^T$ surely isn't zero.

Comment: okay, that is clear now. But where is my problem in thinking? Depends the energy on the momentum? Edit: oooohhh. Energy-momentum-relation of special relativity. Does it work then?

Comment: Apologies, Shawn, you could force me (or someone else) to solve the full problem, but I think that if that happens, it could only be used to cheat. I am not really helping you anymore. You really shouldn't try to solve similar complex problems such as the parameterizations of differential cross section before you are sure enough about the relativistic dispersion relations, among other more basic things. In all these 2-to-2 problems, there are four momenta obeying $p^2=m^2$ with the obvious $m$, and  4-momentum conservation holds. One has to be sure about these matters before more complex stuff